# Linq Excel file prints SYSTEM.LINQ.ENUMERABLE+ instead of value C#

Tags: c#, excel, linq

I am working in C# MVC.  I have a report that is exported into a .csv file and it exports, but I can't seem to get my coding right for grabbing the guts of the file.  I have the column headers and the frame, but the first value I try to pull from the database gives me this long...long string.  I've tried a bunch of combos but my brain isn't seeing the problem.  My code is below.

```
public IEnumerable<SummaryRow> GetSummaryRows(int yearSetupId)
        {
            var x = _db.Items.Select(o => o.ItemPayments.Select(p => p.ItemPaymentSplits.Where(q => q.YearSetupId == yearSetupId))).ToList();
            return x
                .Select(item=> new
                {
                    Year = item.Select(a => a.Select(b => b.YearSetup.Name)).ToString(),
                })
                .AsEnumerable() //  EF barrier
                .Select(i => new SummaryRow()
                {
                    Year = i.Year,
                });
        }
```

Comment: It's a LOT easier to use a library like Epplus to create real xlsx files. Just use `sheet.LoadFromCollection(mySummaryRows)`. Epplus takes care of  types, you avoid conversion problems, *and* you get a much smaller file, since `xlsx` is a zipped collection of XML files

Answer (score 1):

That happens because the data you are getting from that method are type of `IEnumerable<SummaryRow>`

When you save that result to string, `ToString()` method is called. `ToString()` of `IEnumerable<SummaryRow>` is probably result that you get.

I would suggest to create method:

```
public string FlatenSummaryRows(IEnumerable<SymmaryRow> summaryRows) {
    //here make your collection flat
    string result = string.Empty;
    for each (var item in  summaryRows) {
       result += $"this is my item {item.prop1}";
    }
}
```

then just call it against your results from method: `GetSummaryRows`

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to say what's wrong, since you didn't post the code that generates the CSV file. It's a lot easier to generate a real Excel file though, using a library like [Epplus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus):

```
public ActionResult ExportData(int yearSetupId)
{

    //....
    var rows=GetSummaryRows(yearSetupId);

    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("My Sheet");
        //true generates headers
        ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(rows, true);

        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        package.SaveAs(stream);

        string fileName = "myfilename.xlsx";
        string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

        stream.Position = 0;
        return File(stream, contentType, fileName);
    }
}
```

This way you avoid conversion problems due to localization, newlines or separators inside text columns etc.

Epplus uses reflection to find the properties and types in the collection objects and generates the corresponding cells with the appropriate formatting, eg for numbers, dates, etc. `LoadFromCollection` or the equivalent `LoadFromDatatable` return an ExcelRange object that you can use to style the entire range, attach names, generate tables, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up pulling directly from the database and using a where statement.

```
return _db.Items
                .Where(a => a.ItemPayments.Any(b => b.ItemPaymentSplits.Any(c => c.YearSetupId == yearSetupId)))
                .GroupBy(a => yearSetupId)
```